# SDL TTF_OpenFont returns NULL on second attempt

Tags: sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to load a font twice into different TTF_Fonts (for different sizes) with the following code :

```
char const* fontString;
char const* titleFontString;    
//load the string values using libconfig    
try
    {
        fontString = cfg.lookup("font_string");
}
catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
{
}
try
{
   titleFontString = cfg.lookup("title_font_string");
}
catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
{}
font = TTF_OpenFont( fontString, STREAMER_FONT_SIZE/SCREEN_DIMENSION_DIVIDER );
pictureTitleFont = TTF_OpenFont( titleFontString, PICTURE_TITLE_FONT_SIZE/SCREEN_DIMENSION_DIVIDER );'
```

The first will load but the second returns null.  It doesn't matter which order I call them in, always the second fails.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You should test the return value of `TTF_OpenFont` and in case of failure, use `TTF_GetError` to know what's the cause of the error.  I've personally never had problems with it, but maybe it could fail if the font size cannot be supported by the font?  See the documentation for more (very little) information [here](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_14.html).

Comment: The TTF_GetError message is "Couldn't open cinu" whatever that means.  If I swap the order of the font loading it is always the second that fails so it can't be a problem with the way I'm loading it.  Also if I use a string instead of a variable for the font path then it works.  Unfortunately I can't do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: There seems to be something really wrong going on in your program, it would take more code to figure out what's happening.  I don't know where "cinu" comes from, it should display your font name.  Is your code exactly like you described in the initial question?

Comment: I have amended the code to show more detail. What really puzzles me is that when I swap the order of the calls to TTF_OpenFont it is still the second call that fails even thought the two calls ought to be unrelated (with seperate variables feeding the call and receiving the return value).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the help.

I can't find why this was happening but it seems that when calling TTF_OpenFont() the values of **both** strings were changing.
To get around this problem I am getting the values of each string just before calling that specific font.  Not ideal but the problem seems to have gone away for now.

I will do further investigation when time permits and see if I can work out why this was happening.

Thanks again.